# In Visual Studio 2013, what does this black arrow-shaped symbol in the breakpoint bar mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide

Somehow, one of the lines in my source code became marked with a black arrow-shaped icon pointing to the right. I'm familiar with bookmarks and breakpoints, but I can't find a clue about this one. It is the top-most icon in the screenshot below.

What is the purpose of this symbol?

[image: Screenshot of the unknown icon]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That icon indicates that the line is a Find Result from the last time you did a "Find In Files."

Comment: You're right, I made this search ~two hours ago and totally forgot about it.