# What's the purpose of this arrow icon in the left margin / breakpoint bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide

It's been 3.5 years since I asked [a similar question about an unknown symbol in Visual Studio's breakpoint bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915869/in-visual-studio-2013-what-does-this-black-arrow-shaped-symbol-in-the-breakpoin).

However, I stumbled about another one a few days ago. It represents an arrow pointing to the top right corner of a square.
[image]

What does this icon mean?

Comment: I knew there would be a duplicate somewhere, but my searches didn't yield any result. Thanks for bringing this up.